# sed match only in second line

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed

I have a `sed` expression which finds `}` in `config.cfg.lua` and prepends `$JITSI_VIDEOBRIDGE.subdomain.domain.com`:

```
sed -i "s/}/,\"$JITSI_VIDEOBRIDGE.subdomain.domain.com\",}/g" config.cfg.lua
```

Since there are more `}` inside the config file I need to apply this to the 2nd line only, and ignore the rest.

Any ideas?

Comment: OK, lesson learned.
`sed -i "2s/}/,\"$JITSI_VIDEOBRIDGE.subdomain.domain.com\",}/g" config.cfg.lua`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, lesson learned:

```
sed -i "2s/}/,\"$JITSI_VIDEOBRIDGE.subdomain.domain.com\",}/g" config.cfg.lua
```